# Adding a column that contain record number in vb.net datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to make a new column in my datagridview named "No.", i want that column to contain the record number of every record in the datagridview, So if there are 3 records in the datagridview, the column "No." will be like :
1
2
3 
and if there are 4 records, it will be :
1
2
3
4 
and so on.
Please help me, sorry for bad english.
FYI, the other column record is from database.

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769048/how-to-number-the-rows-of-datagridview ?

Comment: yes, but i can't understand because i am very new to vb.net and they are using c#, could you give me a basic code for my question ?

Comment: @Elma Just use a c# / vb.net Converter. Try it out: http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it.

1.By getting the value from the query only where it will have an extra column at the beginning. It depends on which Data Server you are using

Ex: In Oracle,

```
SELECT ROWNUM,COL1 FROM TABLENAME
```

this query can be set as a datasource for the grid.

2.Just by Setting the value for every row header through a simple loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   DataGridViewRowHeaderCell cell = grid.Rows[i].HeaderCell;
   cell.Value = (i + 1).ToString();
   grid.Rows[i].HeaderCell = cell;
}
```